# How to bind datetime function in sqlite3 c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

My sqlite insert statement is as

```
char *testSQL;
testSQL = "INSERT INTO Test (id, tx_time) VALUES ("+id+ ", datetime("+timestamp+",'unixepoch', 'localtime'));";
```

I'm trying to convert above into prepared statement using `sqlite3_bind`.

```
testSQL = "INSERT INTO Test (id, tx_time) VALUES (?, ?);";
```

I can bind `id` simply using `sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, id)` but how can I bind `datetime` function?

Answer (score 1):

Put the `datetime` in the SQL instead:

```
char *testSQL;
testSQL = "INSERT INTO Test (id, tx_time) "
          "VALUES (?, datetime(?,'unixepoch', 'localtime'));"
```

And use `sqlite3_bind_int` to bind `timestamp` instead.